# Does merger control really affect market structure?

Tags: industrial-organisation

Pretty much since 1976 (the passage of Hart-Scott-Rodino Act) US antitrust authorities have been reviewing mergers, challenging only 1.8 per cent of the total number of above-threshold notifications (IIRC I read it in a book by Bob Pitofsky).

What are the studies that control for changes in technology, capital availability and perhaps other factors and quantify the impact of merger control on economy-wide market structure/concentration measures?

Answer (score 6):

Clifford Winston´s [**excellent book**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0815793898) *Government Failure versus Market Failure: 
Microeconomics Policy Research and Government Performance* surveys the literature on the effects of government regulation generally and antitrust merger control specifically. He doesn't exactly answer your question on economy-wide structural effects, but largely concludes that merger control is rather ineffective. A small quote:

> Evidence from the finance literature indicates that mergers that were
>   challenged by the DOJ and the FTC were in general not anticompetitive
>   and would have been efficient had they been allowed to go through
>   ([Eckbo 1992](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1992.tb04003.x)). Mergers that were challenged or opposed by antitrust
>   regulators but were consummated anyway have often resulted in gains
>   for consumers ([Schuman, Reitzes, and Rogers 1997](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/a:1007979005941); Morrison 1996).
>   Finally, Crandall and Winston (2003) analyzed the effects of merger
>   policy on price-cost margins and found that the antitrust authorities
>   have primarily attacked mergers that would enhance efficiency, either
>   by blocking them in court or allowing them to proceed only if the
>   merger partners agreed to conditions that turned out to raise their
>   costs.

Comment: Thanks for posting the ref. Looks like Clifford Winston has the propensity to eschew calculations in the book. Will look further.